# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options). on plain html file

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im trying to implement a basic google sign-in on a simple html page, but for some reason it will not work giving me the error in the title, this is just the basic sign in with pop up function that you can find in the documentation of firebase, i have a button

`<button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-success" id="g_sign" onclick="signInWithPopup">Sign in With Google</button>` 
that is a basic bootstrap button with an onclick attribute to call signinwithpopup

```
  const auth = getAuth();
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      const user = result.user;
      // IdP data available using getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
      // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // The email of the user's account used.
      const email = error.customData.email;
      // The AuthCredential type that was used.
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      // ...
    });
```

I tried adding in the const app in side of the auth constant but that did nothing, hope anyone can help out!
`const auth = getAuth(app);`

I tried adding in google authentication provider using firebase authentication, so I followed the documentation instructions and expected to see a simple pop-up asking to me to choose which google account I want to use, it didnt do that it threw an error in the console, I also looked into other times folks here asked the question and not one of the solutions here seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is because you are using onclick, instead it should be onClick with uppercase C.

```
 <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-success" id="g_sign" onClick="signInWithPopup">Sign in With Google</button>
```